# Extract Youtube ad-button Link with javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-extension

I need to extract a link that is generated on the client side when clicking a button.

[image]
[image: Youtube Ad Button]

When clicking the button the browser opens a new page and redirects the user to the advertiser. How can I get this link?

Answer (score 0):

Just do simple query for that element and get text:

```js
document.querySelector('#visit-advertiser:j .ytp-ad-button-text').textContent
```

Comment: It's not that simple. This is just the button Text the correct URL gets generated somewhere in the client.

Comment: @TotalOne So then provide minimal example, not just screenshot of random HTML. JS can't read variables that are hidden from main scope